# How to re-implement a Dojo application using Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, dojo, esri-leaflet

I apologize in advance if this is not the correct forum to ask my question. I have an web map application developed using the Dojo framework. However I would like to create the same web map application using leaflet. I see that Dojo uses widgets, does leaflet API have something similar to the Dojo widgets that I can use? Is there an example that I can find where someone is using Dojo and leaflet together?

Answer (score 2):

i wrote a quick example of loading dojo and leaflet in the same application [here](http://jsfiddle.net/h7m2csrw/)

that being said, if you are committed to using dojo, it probably makes more sense to maintain a mapping application written with our [ArcGIS API for JavaScript](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/), which loads the framework automatically (and uses it internally) than it does to use Esri Leaflet.

additonal information added on 11/26:
(to answer your follow up question):

there is no comparison chart because you are talking about apples and oranges.  leaflet is a small mapping library with an ecosystem of mapping plugins.  Dojo is a substantially more massive generic JavaScript framework/library with heaps of general purpose widgets to simplify common tasks in all kinds of web applications, not just those with maps.

it makes substantially more sense to compare and contrast the widgets in the ArcGIS API for JavaScript to what is available via Leaflet plugins.  in general, i would characterize the difference like this....

using the ArcGIS API for JavaScript is like shopping at a warehouse store like Costco.  its massive, you'll be able to find pretty much anything you'd need, its good quality and ready to eat, but probably won't be exactly what you're looking for if you're a picky eater.

using esri leaflet is like going to small specialty stores all over town looking for raw ingredients to cook a meal from scratch.  if you have the patience and expertise to hunt and peck, select what you're looking for and prepare the meal just the way you like, it can be a very satisfying experience.  that being said, especially when you're learning, you can also go to a substantial amount of trouble and not have a lot to show for it at the end of the day.

there's no wrong or right answer.  its just different strokes for different folks.

hope that helps.

Comment: Hi John, thank for your quick response. I'm not committed to using dojo, but I'm committed to using esri-leaflets, but I'm finding out that a lot of the things in the existing application is doing it with the widgets provided by dojo. And I'm not sure if there's anything in esri-leaflets or plugins that come close to what dojo is doing...Is there such a thing as a chart comparison of leaflet plugins and dojo widgets?