# Why can't I load my basemap from the ArcGIS rest services using leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, wms, web-mapping

Why can't I load my basemap from the ArcGIS rest services using leaflet ? do I need to include"the esri-leaflet" package as well to use ArcGIS rest services in leaflet?*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="leaflet.css"/>
        <!--[if lte IE 8]>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="leaflet/leaflet.ie.css"/>
        <![endif]-->
        <script src="leaflet.js"></script>
        <style>
            html, body, #map {
                height:100%;
            }
            body {
                padding:0;
                margin:0;
                }
        </style>
        <title>Getting Started with Leaflet</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var map=L.map('map',{
                center:[52.48,-1.89],
                zoom:14
            });
            L.marker([52.48,-1.89],{
                clickable:true
            })
                .bindPopup('Hello Birmingham!')
                .addTo(map);
            L.marker([52.48,-1.900],{
                clickable:true,
                draggable:true,
                icon:L.icon({
                    iconUrl:'images/packtpub.png',
                    iconAnchor:[32,32],
                    popupAnchor:[32,10]
                })
            })
                .bindPopup('Hello custom!')
                .addTo(map);
            L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',{attribution:'&copy; OpenStreetMap contributors'}).addTo(map);
            var hydro=L.tileLayer.wms('http://apps.geoportal.icimod.org/icimodarcgis/rest/services/HKH/AnnualSolarRadiation/MapServer',{
                
                format:'image/png',
                transparent:true,
                attribution:'Contains British Geological Survey materials NERC 2013',
                opacity:0.25
                });
            var soil =L.tileLayer.wms('http://apps.geoportal.icimod.org/icimodarcgis/rest/services/HKH/AnnualSolarRadiation/MapServer',{

                format:'image/png',
                transparent:true,
                attribution:'Contains British Geological Survey materials NERC 2013'});
            var firstGroup = L.layerGroup([
                L.marker([52.486,-1.890]),
                L.marker([52.488,-1.890]),
                L.marker([52.490,-1.890]),
                L.marker([52.483,-1.890]),
                L.marker([52.482,-1.880]),
                hydro
                ]).addTo(map);
            var secondGroup = L.layerGroup([
                L.marker([52.4846,-1.900]),
                L.marker([52.487,-1.890]),
                L.marker([52.489,-1.896]),
                L.marker([52.484,-1.894]),
                L.marker([52.4862,-1.880]),
                soil
                ]);
            map.on('click',function(e){
                if (map.hasLayer(firstGroup)){
                    map.removeLayer(firstGroup);
                    map.addLayer(secondGroup);
                } else{
                    map.removeLayer(secondGroup);
                    map.addLayer(firstGroup);
                    }
                });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at https://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/examples/showing-a-basemap.html notice at the beginning they have Leaflet and Esri libraries defined. You are missing this in your code. https://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/examples/tile-layer-1.html may also help.  Here is an example of your data in a map,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <title>Leaflet</title>
  <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />

  <!-- Load Leaflet from CDN-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.1.0/dist/leaflet.css"
    integrity="sha512-wcw6ts8Anuw10Mzh9Ytw4pylW8+NAD4ch3lqm9lzAsTxg0GFeJgoAtxuCLREZSC5lUXdVyo/7yfsqFjQ4S+aKw=="
    crossorigin=""/>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.1.0/dist/leaflet-src.js"
    integrity="sha384-TWB9xRHTlLQmqAngHwD7usGcf4akGf0JP6aHwlgilpmOu2UuBq5aWLsDAh39iSn1"
    crossorigin=""></script>


  <!-- Load Esri Leaflet from CDN -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/esri-leaflet@2.0.8"
    integrity="sha384-ze7rgny7/YGFxBlVgTBdOABNWe5V9BYjju/qwqJhCU8XJHtuEnRlbUpN5lXyY706"
    crossorigin=""></script>

  <style>
    body { margin:0; padding:0; }
    #map { position: absolute; top:0; bottom:0; right:0; left:0; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="map"></div>

<script>
  var map = L.map('map').setView([31.2973,85.0561], 3);

  //Loading Basemaps

  var Gray =L.esri.basemapLayer('Gray').addTo(map);

  var osm= L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',{attribution:'© OpenStreetMap contributors'}); 

 var topo = L.esri.tiledMapLayer({
    url: "https://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/USA_Topo_Maps/MapServer"
  });

 var soil = L.esri.dynamicMapLayer({
    url: 'http://apps.geoportal.icimod.org/icimodarcgis/rest/services/HKH/AnnualSolarRadiation/MapServer',
    opacity: 0.7
  });

   var hydro = L.esri.dynamicMapLayer({
    url: 'http://apps.geoportal.icimod.org/icimodarcgis/rest/services/HKH/AnnualSolarRadiation/MapServer',
    opacity: 0.7
  });

  /// END Loading Basemaps

   //MapService as a Dynamic Layer  //Symbology comes from ArcServer Service
    outline =  L.esri.dynamicMapLayer({
        url:'http://apps.geoportal.icimod.org/icimodarcgis/rest/services/HKH/Outline/MapServer',
        //layers: [2],
        opacity : 1
    });

    //Put markers & grouplayers here

    // END Put markers & grouplayers here
var baseMaps = {
    "Esri Gray":Gray,
    "Topo":topo,
    "Open Street Map": osm,
    "Water":hydro,
    "Dirt":soil
};

var overlayMaps ={
"Outline":outline
};

layerControl = L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlayMaps).addTo(map);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks alot Bill ! I have one more question though.. Can we use dojo utilities via this esri-leaflet API?

Comment: You can if you want to but dojo is usually associated with ArcGIS JS not Leaflet. If your planning on using ArcGIS JS you don't need to use the esri-leaflet api. Leaflet is mostly used with plain JavaScript and some JQuery where it make sense, making it a lighter and easier to program app.

Comment: Thanks for replying Bill ! Actually, the code that I am working now is not my work ..Before this I did all my  codes  using ArcGIS JS API.. so for the same task I did before I had to do it all over again for this leaflet version..Argh.. If only I could use the same code here too.... I tried but couldnt find any useful plugins for running dojo in leaflet! Please help me if you know something!

Comment: There have been some attempts and Google turned up this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/123441/how-to-re-implement-a-dojo-application-using-leaflet It should be noted John is an Esri employee who has lots of experience with the Esri-leaflet library. If your not using custom predefined widgets it should be a short learning curve. Dojo is what makes the ArcGIS JS tougher to learn.